# Refresh DataSource and update GridControl

Tags: c#, devexpress, entity-framework-5

i will try to explain my problem here...

I work with 2 forms. first one have Drop down menu and grid control that is populated after selecting item in drop down menu. after populating gridControl, I have a button to add new row with data. When i click it, new form opens with textFields to fill, and save button to save changes and refresh gridControl.
Here is code from first form where gridControl is populated after select item in dropDown menu:

```
private void ddScoreType_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddScoreTypeSelectedID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LookUpEdit).EditValue);
        try
        {
            gcScoreParam.DataSource = null;
            gvScoreParam.Columns.Clear();
            selectedScoreType = _db.ScoreTypes.Where(x => x.ID == ddScoreTypeSelectedID).SingleOrDefault();
            gcScoreParam.DataSource = selectedScoreType.ScoreParams.ToList();

            gvScoreParam.Columns.AddVisible("Name", "Name");
            gvScoreParam.Columns.AddVisible("Code", "Code");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

That works fine...
Here is code from my second input form where i should add new data and refresh gridControl in first form:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //XtraMessageBox.Show("ID - " + _ScoresTypeID);
        db = new BetEntities();
        ScoreParam param = new ScoreParam();

        db.ScoreParams.Add(param);
        param.ScoreTypeID = _ScoresTypeID;
        param.Name = txtScoreName.Text;
        param.Code = txtScoreCode.Text.ToUpper();

        db.SaveChanges();

        frmScoreType frmST = new frmScoreType();
        frmST.RefreshGVParams(db);

        this.Close();
    }
```

db is  my database and ScoreParam is table.
Here is method RefreshGVParams:

```
public void RefreshGVParams(BetEntities be)
    {
        //gvScoreParam.BeginDataUpdate();
        gcScoreParam.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            gcScoreParam.DataSource = null;      // this line DOES NOT set datasource to null
            selectedScoreType = be.ScoreTypes.Where(x => x.ID == ddScoreTypeSelectedID).SingleOrDefault();
            gcScoreParam.DataSource = selectedScoreType.ScoreParams.ToList();
            gvScoreParam.Columns.Clear();
            gvScoreParam.Columns.AddVisible("Name", "Name");
            gvScoreParam.Columns.AddVisible("Code", "Code");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        { 
            gcScoreParam.EndUpdate();
            //gvScoreParam.EndDataUpdate();
        }
    }
```

I commented the line that doesn't set dataSource to null, and gridcontrol is not refreshed with new data... 
when i close my first form and start it again, then i see it refreshed with new data...

How can i refresh gridControl in first form after clicking SAVE button in second form ? Where I made misstake ?

Sorry for long post, but it's been 2 days since i can't solve this problem... I hope I explained well :)

Answer (score 0):

Add/Replace the following code in the Add new row button click event assuming your second form name is Form2

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog();
RefreshGVParams((BetEntities)f2.Tag);
```

On your Form2 Change btnSave_Click code to

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    db = new BetEntities();
    ScoreParam param = new ScoreParam();

    db.ScoreParams.Add(param);
    param.ScoreTypeID = _ScoresTypeID;
    param.Name = txtScoreName.Text;
    param.Code = txtScoreCode.Text.ToUpper();

    db.SaveChanges();

    this.Tag = db; 

    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In btnSave_Click, when you create a new form object `frmScoreType frmST = new frmScoreType();` you no longer reference your first opened form. `gcScoreParam.DataSource = null;` in you case sets the data source to null for the new object you created and not for your opened form.
Try using `(frmScoreType)Application.OpenForms["frmScoreType"].RefreshGVParams(db);`
and now your function RefreshGVParams will be executed by the opened form. 
Or you can also take control of your opened form like this :
`frmScoreType f = (frmScoreType)Application.OpenForms["frmScoreType"]` and first check if `f == null` (to see if your form is opened, and after that call `f.RefreshGVParams(db);`
Please excuse my english. Hope it helps.